# How do I add State into dynamic UI controls?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to add some state to some dynamic UI controls created with ReactJS. I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.setState is not a function
```

I've basically got a really good sample from a pen of recursively generating UI controls based on some JSON - I've made them controlled components (by adding value/checked properties to the controls).

This is all good, however, none of the UI controls update (so a checkbox does not uncheck in the UI if it is originally checked). So to fix this I'm now trying to add State to it so the UI works correctly. I'm really not sure if this is the correct way to go or if I should just make them all uncontrolled components and use refs - but this apparently is not best practice according to the react documentation.

I've added in a `onChange` event on the `InputGroup`. This calls `inputChangedHandler` function and in this I'm trying to `setState` - this is where I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.setState is not a function
```

on this line:

```
this.setState({ input: event.target.checked });
```

I think that the reason why it's failing at this point is that there is no `setState` method on `this` so I'm not sure how to pass through the correct 'this'. I've initialized the state inside the constructor which I think is the correct thing to do. I think it's just a matter of being able to use that `setState` method on the correct `this`.

```
//Component defined for text, date, numeric and checkbox)
const InputGroup = props => { 
    const types = { "Text": 'text', "Date": 'date', "Numeric": "number", "CheckBox": "checkbox" }
    return (
         //The props.value relates to JSX attribute names for the inputgroup below
        <div className="input-groupDynamic">
            <label className="labelD" htmlFor={props.label.replace(" ", "-")}>{props.label}</label>
            <input name={props.label.replace(" ", "-")}
                type={types[props.type]}

                //uncontrolled components code
                //defaultValue={props.value}
                //defaultChecked={props.value}

                //controlled components code
                value={props.value}
                checked={props.value}
                onChange={this.inputChangedHandler.bind(this)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

//arrow function 
inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.target.type == 'checkbox') {
        alert('new value : ' + event.target.checked);

        this.setState({ saveCareersUrlVisible: event.target.checked });

    } else {
        alert('new value : ' + event.target.value);
    }
}

//arrow function 
inputChangedHandler = (event, data) => {
    if (event.target.type == 'checkbox') {
        this.setState({ input: event.target.checked });

    } else {
        //to do....
    }
}

const renderChildren = children => {    
    //This is the bit that does a recursive-ish rendering of children....using the .map to map over the JSON data return children? children.map((child, ind) => {

        //Using 'const' as the variable won’t be reassigned.
        const newChildren = child.children ? [...child.children] : [];
        const { containerType, title, input, label, options, value, ref } = child

        //Using 'let' as this is a variable that may be reassigned
        let key;  
        let actualDate;

        if (typeof (input) !== 'undefined' && input == "Date" && typeof (value) !== 'undefined') {
            //console.log("control type : " + input);
            actualDate = new Date(value).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
        }
        //console.log("Date from JSON :" + (typeof (date) !== 'undefined' ? date : '2001-01-01'));
        //console.log("Converted Date:" + test.toString());
        //console.log("initial date value: " + date);
        if (newChildren.length) {
            key = `${containerType}-${ind}`;
            switch (containerType) {    
                case "Tabs":
                    return <Tabs
                        key={key}
                        title={title}
                        children={newChildren}
                    />
                case "Column":
                    return <Column
                        key={key}
                        title={title}
                        children={newChildren}
                    />
                case "Row":
                    return <Row
                        key={key}
                        title={title}
                        children={newChildren}
                    />
                default:
                    return <Common
                        key={key}
                        title={title}
                        children={newChildren}
                    />
            }
        } else {
            console.log("control type : " + input);
            console.log("ref : " + ref);

            key = `${input}-${ind}`
            console.log("key : " + key);

            switch (input) {
                case "ComboBox":
                    return <SelectGroup
                        key={key}
                        label={label}
                        options={options}
                    />
                case "Text":
                case "Numeric":
                    return <InputGroup
                        key={key}
                        label={label}
                        type={input}
                        value={value}
                        //ref={ref}
                    />
                case "Date":
                    return <InputGroup
                        key={key}
                        label={label}
                        type={input}
                        value={actualDate}
                        //ref={key}
                    />
                case "CheckBox":
                    return <InputGroup
                        key={key}
                        label={label}
                        type={input}
                        value={value}
                        //onChange={e => this.setState({ SaveCareersUrlVisible: props.label.replace(" ", "-" + e.value) })}
                    />
                case "Button":
                    return <ButtonGroup
                        key={key}
                        type={input}
                        onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmitClick(e)}
                    ></ButtonGroup>
            }
        }

    }) : null
}

class App extends React.Component {
    //Class constructor 
    constructor(props) {
        // Pass props to the parent component
        super(props)
        // Set initial state, use spread notation and pass entire object (the JSON data in this case) - this will unpack it into the props
        this.state = {
            saveCareersUrlVisible: "",
            ...props.config
        }; 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        alert("componentDidMount");
    }

    handleSubmitClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);

        this.setState({
            myvalues: stringifyFormData(data),
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { title, children, saveCareersUrlVisible } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container title={title} children={children} saveCareersUrlVisible={saveCareersUrlVisible}/>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to call `setState` (at some point) when the user, for example, clicks on a checkbox, it re-renders the state and updates the UI - so the checkbox unchecks or checks in the UI.

What its actually doing is erroring on `setState` - so the impact is that the UI does not get updated, even though the `onChange` event fires and I can pick up the changed value. Note: If I remove the setting of 'state' completely then the UI does not get updated which is why I want to add 'state' into my solution.

Comment: remove  onChange={this.inputChangedHandler.bind(this)} and make it  onChange={this.inputChangedHandler}

Comment: OK I'll give it a try, thank you....

Comment: Also you have to pass it down by props

Comment: Mosè Raguzzini...that didn't make any difference - the onChange() method was still called - not sure setState is valid from here according to post by Sagiv b g

Comment: I'm setting props.config onto this.state in the constructor, do I need to do something else here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `this.inputChangedHandler` but note that `InputGroup` is not a `class` but a `function`.

Beside, there is no `setState` inside regular functions, this is a method you get by creating a `class` that extends `React.Component`

In short, if you want `setState` (or any other react specific features) you'll need to use a `class` and extend from [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

So this is how it should look like more or less:

```
class InputGroup extends React.Component {

    state = { saveCareersUrlVisible: false } // initial state

    //arrow function 
    inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.target.type == 'checkbox') {
            alert('new value : ' + event.target.checked);

            this.setState({ saveCareersUrlVisible: event.target.checked });

        } else {
            alert('new value : ' + event.target.value);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const types = { "Text": 'text', "Date": 'date', "Numeric": "number", "CheckBox": "checkbox" }
        return (
            //The props.value relates to JSX attribute names for the inputgroup below
            <div className="input-groupDynamic">
                <label className="labelD" htmlFor={this.props.label.replace(" ", "-")}>{this.props.label}</label>
                <input name={this.props.label.replace(" ", "-")}
                    type={types[this.props.type]}

                    //uncontrolled components code
                    //defaultValue={props.value}
                    //defaultChecked={props.value}

                    //controlled components code
                    value={this.props.value}
                    checked={this.props.value}
                    onChange={this.inputChangedHandler.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment Sagiv - so you said "this is a method you get by creating a class that extends React.Component" - I'm already creating a class that does this - do I need to pass something down so that its available in the inputChangeHandler() ?

Comment: You're not using a `class` that does it regarding `InputGroup`. if this component needs to call `setState` then it should be a `class` that extends `React.Component`. You can see the example i posted

Comment: Hi @Sagiv b g thank you very much for your help, it sort of works - well I don't get the error now - however as I'm now setting the value of the checkbox from state, at the top of the InputGroup class, it's not initialising to the correct values (so as in the JSON value) - is there a way to have all of the dynamic controls in state - like using their names, initialised from the JSON ? sorry not sure if I've clearly explained this! - I can clarify if required

Comment: so looked at this a bit more...Yes, originally the value was being set from the props, so not sure if this is relevant now that I want to get the value from state to make the ui update

Comment: Just to say thank you for your assistance with this sagiv-b-g - getting there now